# Is this algorithm starvation free?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency

I've stumbled upon a modified version of the Bakerys Algorithm (an uncomplete one of course with flaws)

I've been asked in class if the following algorithm is can have a starvation issue:

```
while(true){
    number[me] = max(number[0],...,number[n]) + 1
    for (other from 0 to n) {
        while(number[other] != 0 && number[other] < number[me]) {
            // Wait
        }
    }

    /*CS*/
    number[me] = 0
}
```

I understand that a deadlock is possible however, I'm asking is this algorithm starvation-free ?

I think that it is, because I can guarantee that once `thread A` has chosen a number, other threads will always have a bigger number than `thread A` and therefor he will eventually be allowed to enter the CS

My friend thinks that the algorithm is not starvation free, since a thread can be stuck in the process of taking a number (calculating the `max`) and possibly get its CPU time taken from him. Meanwhile other threads will start & finish and perhaps start again (since the while true) while supposedly `thread A` is being starved.

**My question can be simplified to this:**
Does the `choosing` array in the original Bakerys Algorithm solve starvation ?

Comment: "a thread can be stuck in the process of taking a number (calculating the max) and possibly get its CPU time taken from him" I suppose that's technically true, but I think it's a safe assumption (at least in the context of an academic problem) that it's not that expensive of an operation for a thread to not be able to finish executing.

Comment: I'm talking theoretically of course, from an academic approach

Answer (score 3):

**Starvation-freedom** can be defined as: Any process trying to enter critical section, will eventually enter critical section.

The line that calculates `max` is not part of the critical section, so it will eventually receive cpu time to make that assignment.

When a `process A` receives its `id`, then it will wait for all the other process that has an `id` lower than the one it has (lower id means that has more priority). Sometime that processes will leave the critical section and will get a new `id`. This id will be greater than the one it has and in that moment `process A` will enter in the critical section.

Finally, the algorithm is starvation-free.